# Populating a bootstrap 3 dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to populate this drop down with comments but only end up with the first comment instead of all of them.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Comments
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <% @comments.each do |z| %>
      <% if z.post_id == post.id %>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><%= z.body %></li>
    </ul>
</div>
  <% end %>
```

controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order(created_at: :desc)
        @comment = Comment.new
        @comments = Comment.all
    end 
end
```

Comment: Can you please share your controller code as well. The reason is I think you are following a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is due to html structure or your post have only 1 comment. Try this

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Comments
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <% @comments.each do |z| %>
        <li><%= z.body %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The reason is I think in your controller  you might have fatched `post` and its related comments (`post.comments`), so you do not need to check for the post.

**Update:**
As you have updated  your question you should change your controller as well.

```
 Post.include(:comments).all.order(created_at: :desc)
```

Within your partial instead of `@comments` use `post.comments` It will work perfectly. Reason of doing this is performance issue. Notice now you are making a single query and saved condition check within look. Now take eg that you have 1000 post. You will iterate over 1000 post and each post have 1000 comments it will check for all? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Your code did get it to list every comment, just not for the correct posts.  I should be able to figure it out from here.